# python3.6 venv not finding correct path

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv, pyenv

I'm answering my own question here, to save someone else the 2 hours I spent figuring this out.

Also, although this is a python3.6 problem, I imagine that same gotcha will apply to 2.7

I'm running a venv on ubuntu 18.04 where the default python is 2.7. Before I decided to create a venv I had to specify `python3.6` to get the correct version of python for my project.

I then decided (as proper practice) to use a venv. I created the venv like this:

```
python3.6 -m venv .
```

from the directory I was working in. Then -

```
pip install pyopenssl
```

I ran my script as I had been - the shebang is #! `/usr/bin/python3.6`

```
./sslchecker.py
```

and got an error that it failed to load the OpenSSL library.

So I tried this:

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/dominic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
>>>
```

No mention of my current directory whatsoever? What gives?

Comment: your shebang should probably be `#!/usr/bin/env python3.6`

Answer (score 1):

I was using the system python3.6, not the one in the venv.

The trick was to deactivate the venv, then delete the system folders from it (probably not entirely necessary, but I wasn't entirely sure what mess I'd made as I was hacking around)

```
$ deactivate
dominic at dominic-ThinkPad-X220 in ~/ssl-checker on master*
$ rm -rf bin include lib lib64 __pycache__ pyvenv.cfg share
```

Then

```
dominic at dominic-ThinkPad-X220 in ~/ssl-checker on master*
$ python3.6 -m venv .
dominic at dominic-ThinkPad-X220 in ~/ssl-checker on master*
$ source bin/activate
(ssl-checker) dominic at dominic-ThinkPad-X220 in ~/ssl-checker on master*
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9
(ssl-checker) dominic at dominic-ThinkPad-X220 in ~/ssl-checker on master*
$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/dominic/ssl-checker/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>>
```

just saying `python` within the venv, rather than specifying `python3.6`, was the real key to the problem.